# MACOS: Error using P2D argument in JAVA (ECLIPSE IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, processing

**ERROR**

2022-09-01 13:17:41.599 java[13634:814287] Apple AWT Internal Exception: NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!

2022-09-01 13:17:41.599 java[13634:814287] trace: (

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff817215e7b __exceptionPreprocess +242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff816f77e48 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81723e8a6 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   AppKit                              0x00007ff819b372f4 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme)_postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 321
4   AppKit                              0x00007ff819b232a4 -[NSWindow_initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1288
5   AppKit                              0x00007ff819b22d96 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
6   libnativewindow_macosx.jnilib       0x000000015c066f9e Java_jogamp_nativewindow_macosx_OSXUtil_CreateNSWindow0 + 398
7   ???                                 0x000000010c1c6187 0x0 + 4498153863
```

)

2022-09-01 13:17:41.599 java[13634:814287] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'

*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff817215e7b __exceptionPreprocess + 242

```
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff816f77e48 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff81723e8a6 -[NSException raise] + 9
3   AppKit                              0x00007ff819b372f4 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 321
4   AppKit                              0x00007ff819b232a4 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1288
5   AppKit                              0x00007ff819b22d96 -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
6   libnativewindow_macosx.jnilib       0x000000015c066f9e Java_jogamp_nativewindow_macosx_OSXUtil_CreateNSWindow0 + 398
7   ???                                 0x000000010c1c6187 0x0 + 4498153863
```

)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

**CODE**

```
package module1;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.UnfoldingMap;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.geo.Location;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.AbstractMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.Google;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.providers.MBTilesMapProvider;
import de.fhpotsdam.unfolding.utils.MapUtils;

/** HelloWorld
  * An application with two maps side-by-side zoomed in on different locations.
  * Author: UC San Diego Coursera Intermediate Programming team
  * @author Your name here
  * Date: July 17, 2015
  * */
public class HelloWorld extends PApplet
{
    /** Your goal: add code to display second map, zoom in, and customize the background.
     * Feel free to copy and use this code, adding to it, modifying it, etc.  
     * Don't forget the import lines above. */

    // You can ignore this.  It's to keep eclipse from reporting a warning
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** This is where to find the local tiles, for working without an Internet connection */
    public static String mbTilesString = "blankLight-1-3.mbtiles";
    
    // IF YOU ARE WORKING OFFLINE: Change the value of this variable to true
    private static final boolean offline = true;
    
    /** The map we use to display our home town: La Jolla, CA */
    UnfoldingMap map1;
    
    /** The map you will use to display your home town */ 
    UnfoldingMap map2;

    public void setup() {
        size(800, 600, P2D);  // Set up the Applet window to be 800x600
                              // The OPENGL argument indicates to use the 
                              // Processing library's 2D drawing
                              // You'll learn more about processing in Module 3

        // This sets the background color for the Applet.  
        // Play around with these numbers and see what happens!
        this.background(200, 200, 200);
        
        
        // Select a map provider
        AbstractMapProvider provider = new Google.GoogleTerrainProvider();
        // Set a zoom level
        int zoomLevel = 10;
        
        if (offline) {
            // If you are working offline, you need to use this provider 
            // to work with the maps that are local on your computer.  
            provider = new MBTilesMapProvider(mbTilesString);
            // 3 is the maximum zoom level for working offline
            zoomLevel = 3;
        }
        
        // Create a new UnfoldingMap to be displayed in this window.  
        // The 2nd-5th arguments give the map's x, y, width and height
        // When you create your map we want you to play around with these 
        // arguments to get your second map in the right place.
        // The 6th argument specifies the map provider.  
        // There are several providers built-in.
        // Note if you are working offline you must use the MBTilesMapProvider
        map1 = new UnfoldingMap(this, 50, 50, 25, 25, provider);

        // The next line zooms in and centers the map at 
        // 32.9 (latitude) and -117.2 (longitude)
        map1.zoomAndPanTo(zoomLevel, new Location(32.9f, -117.2f));
        
        // This line makes the map interactive
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map1);
        
        // TODO: Add code here that creates map2 
        // Then you'll modify draw() below
        
        map2 = new UnfoldingMap(this, 350, 350, 25, 25, provider);

        // The next line zooms in and centers the map at 
        // 32.9 (latitude) and -117.2 (longitude)
        map2.zoomAndPanTo(zoomLevel, new Location(72.9f, -217.2f));
        
        // This line makes the map interactive
        MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map2);

    }

    /** Draw the Applet window.  */
    public void draw() {
        // So far we only draw map1...
        // TODO: Add code so that both maps are displayed
        map1.draw();
        
//      map2.draw();
    }

    
}
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

The application runs once i remove the P2D argument, not sure what the issue is. As suggested by some of the answers, I tried using the older versions of JRE- (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/tag/jdk8u242-b08) but I am getting the same error.

Comment: Possibly specify `-XstartOnFirstThread` on the java command.

Comment: @Maverick Is this on a newer mac (using M1) ? If so, you might need to use [Processing 4.0b9](https://github.com/processing/processing4/releases/tag/processing-1284-4.0b9) or [newer](https://github.com/processing/processing4/releases). (Otherwise, what mac model and OS version and Processing version are you using ?)

Comment: Try running Examples/UnfoldingMaps/SimpleMapApp in Processing IDE v. 4.0.1 and see if you can run it.  It contains size(800, 600, P2D); in setup() and runs ok on my Mac(OS 11.6).